# Vue + Typescript + Webpack: Module build failing - Can't find vue.esm.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to build a basic project using typescript, webpack and vue.js. However, when i run `webpack` from the command line, I am currently getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js
Module build failed: Error: Could not find file: 'c:\Users\user\Games\javascriptTimeGame\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.esm.js'.
    at getValidSourceFile (c:\Users\user\Games\javascriptTimeGame\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:89078:23)
    at Object.getEmitOutput (c:\Users\user\Games\javascriptTimeGame\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:89448:30)
    at getEmit (c:\Users\user\Games\javascriptTimeGame\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:122:43)
    at successLoader (c:\Users\user\Games\javascriptTimeGame\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:42:11)
    at Object.loader (c:\Users\user\Games\javascriptTimeGame\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:29:12)
```

This is strange, because the file it says it can't find is definitely there.

My main script: `script.ts`, looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

function main(){
  let vueApp = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-test",
    data : {
      message: "Hello World"
    }
  });
}

main();
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave":  true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "../jsDist",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

My `package.json` dev dependencies look like:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vue": "^2.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.3",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "watch": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

And my `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: "./ts/script.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: `${__dirname}/jsDist`
    },
    module: {
        rules : [
            {
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
    }
}
```

A few things I've noticed that might isolate the problem.

First, If I simply run `tsc` to directly build my source files with the typescript compiler, then it works perfectly without error. This suggests there is something wrong with the webpack part specifically.

Second, If I alter `script.ts` to just be:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

function main(){
  console.log("Harmless");
}

main();
```

Then webpack builds it without fuss. This suggests that it is not the top-line import that webpack seems to have a problem with, but specifically the *usage* of Vue.

Finally if I alter my webpack.config.js such that ts-loader has the additional option `transpileOnly: true` then it also seems to build without fuss (but of course I don't want to do this, as then I lose my reason for using typescript in the first place!)

Any ideas what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

let vueApp = {};

if (document.querySelector('#authorities-container')) {
  vueApp = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-test",
    data : {
      message: "Hello World"
    }
  });
};

export {vueApp}
```